# Expectation of a function of pairs of random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

For positive random variables $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$, suppose that $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ have the same distribution and (the two pairs) are independent. Also suppose that $E[Y_1|X_1] = \theta X_1$. Let $Z=\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{X_1+X_2}$. Find $E[Z]$.

Solution attempt: Using Law of Iterated Expectations (LIE), we have that $E[Y_1]=\theta E[X_1]$.

We can also write $Z=\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{X_1+X_2}$ as $\frac{Y_1}{X_1 + X_2} + \frac{Y_2}{X_1 + X_2}$.

So, $E[Z]=E[\frac{Y_1}{X_1 + X_2} + \frac{Y_2}{X_1 + X_2}] = E[\frac{Y_1}{X_1 + X_2}] + E[\frac{Y_2}{X_1 + X_2}]$. Now, I tried to use LIE again to get:

$E[Z] = E_{X_1+X2}E[\frac{Y_1}{X_1 + X_2} | X_1+X_2]+... = E_{X_1+X2}[\frac{1}{X_1+X_2}E[Y_1|X_1+X_2]] +...$

Now I have no idea what to do. Can I still treat the $\frac{1}{X_1+X_2}$ as a constant and take it out? I don't think so. How do I proceed from here?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIE three times, then simply because of  independence of the two coordinates w.r.t. each other.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[Z] & = \mathsf E_{X_1}\left[\mathsf E_{X_2\mid X_1}\left[\mathsf E_{Y_1\mid X_1,X_2}\left[\mathsf E_{Y_2\mid X_1,X_2,Y_1}\left[\frac{Y_1+Y_2}{X_1+X_2}\middle| X_1,X_2,Y_1\right]\middle| X_1,X_2\right]\middle| X_1\right]\right]
\\[2ex]
& = \mathsf E_{X_1}\left[\mathsf E_{X_2\mid X_1}\left[\mathsf E_{Y_1\mid X_1,X_2}\left[\frac{Y_1+\mathsf E_{Y_2\mid X_2}[Y_2\mid X_2]}{X_1+X_2}\middle| X_1,X_2\right]\middle| X_1\right]\right]
\\ & \vdots
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf E_{X_1}\left[\mathsf E_{X_2}\left[\frac{\mathsf E_{Y_1\mid X_1}\left[Y_1\mid X_1\right]+\mathsf E_{Y_2\mid X_2}\left[\mathsf Y_2\mid X_2\right]}{X_1+X_2}\right]\right]
\\ & \vdots
\end{align}$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Don't split the numerator. Use both $E[Y_1|X_1] = \theta X_1$ and $E[Y_2|X_2] = \theta X_2$.

Comment: Ok...so I would have $E_{X_1+X_2}[\frac{1}{X_1+X_2}E[Y_1+Y_2|X_1+X_2]]$ but then is $E[Y_1+Y_2|X_1+X_2]=2\theta E[X]$?

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: "Don't split the numerator." Sorry but this is rather moot, one can split or not split (and, sooner or later, it is simpler to split, I believe).

Comment: @Did In this case you have to resist the temptation and not split the numerator. This way the numerator and denominator cancel and leave the answer $\theta$. Of course, you can split and join back, but that would be a bit pointless.

Comment: Rereading the question, I have to disagree with your comment and with the hint in your answer. For example, to know $E(Y_1\mid X_1)$ is not enough to conclude, one needs to identify $E(Y_1\mid X_1,X_2)$. And to do *that*, splitting is simpler... Or, one masters conditioning well enough to see right away what $E(Y_1+Y_2\mid X_1,X_2)$ is, but then one would not ask the question in the first place.